# Creating a series of numbers in Red language

Tags: list, rebol, red

I have a few simple questions, hence I am putting them together:

1. What is the best way to create a series of numbers. Following works but is there a simpler method like 1:10 available in some languages?

   `myseries: []`

   `repeat i 10 [append myseries i]`

   `print myseries`

(1a. Why is above code not making usual code block on this page?)

2. Similarly, what is the best way to create a series of 10 elements,  all initialized to 0 or ""? Do I have to use there also `repeat i 10` or `loop 10` and serially `append` an initially blank series?
3. Also, should I specify the number of elements as in following code while creating the series initially? What is the disadvantage of not doing this?

   myseries: make block! 10

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is definitely one of the things I feel should be easier to do. However, one of the reasons it isn't that way already is the focus is on acting on the data directly rather than generating a series before hand. Still, lots of other array processing features on my wish list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I do not know about a better way at this time, although on [https://gitter.im/red/...](https://gitter.im/red/home) there are discussions about a range data type or **for** implementations

a) It makes a block. You see that with `probe myseries`. What do you expect?

2) `>> append/dup [] 0 10
== [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

3) If you do not initialize/reserve the needed memory, **Red** has to make a guess how much memory is needed. This can be more than needed or less. If less then Red has to allocate another chunk of memory. This can happen a few times if you need more memory. Maybe it has to move around memory blocks too if it wants continuous memory, but  I do not know about the strategy used.

Answer (score 6):

1) My preference would be to go with [COLLECT](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/collect.html) here:

```
myseries: collect [repeat i 10 [keep i]]
```

2) See [ARRAY](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/array.html) function:

```
>> array/initial 10 0
== [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

You can also pass it a anonymous function:

```
>> i: 0 array/initial 10 does [i: i + 1]
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

3) Generally it is good practise to use `myseries: make block! 10` (or just 0 if size of block is unknown) to avoid unnecessary gotchas!  See [To copy or not to copy, that is the question](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/r3blog.r?view=0006) & [Is REBOL a Pure Functional Language?](http://www.rebol.com/article/0206.html)